# SAS : Select rows from a relationnal database

Tags: sas, odbc

I work with SAS on a relationnal database that I can access with a libname odbc statement as below :

```
libname myDBMS odbc datasrc="myDBMS";
```

Say the database contains a table named 'myTable' with a numeric variable 'var_ex' which values can be 0,1 or . (missing). Now say I want to exclude all rows for which var_ex=1.

If I use the following :

```
DATA test1;
SET myDBMS.myTable;  /* I call directly the table from the DBMS */
where var_ex NE 1;
run;
```

I don't get rows for which 'var_ex' is missing. Here is a screenshot of the log, with my actual data :

[image]

Whereas if I do the exact same thing after importing the table in the Work :

```
DATA myTable;        /* I put myTable in the Work library */
SET myDBMS.myTable;
run;
DATA test2;
SET myTable;  /* I call the table from the work */
where var_ex NE 1;
run;
```

I select rows for which 'var_ex' is 0 or missing, as intended. Here is a screenshot of the log, with my actual data :
[image]

The same happens if I use `PROC SQL` instead of a DATA step, or another `NE`-like.
I did some research and more or less understood [here](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/acreldb/63647/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a001353892.htm) that unintended stuff like that can happen if you work directly on a DBMS table.

#### Does that mean is it simply not recommended to work with a DBMS table, and one has to import table locally as below before doing anything ?

```
DATA myTable;        /* I put myTable in the Work library */
SET myDBMS.myTable;
run;
```

Or is there a proper way to manipulate such tables ?

Comment: Can you post your log that shows this occurring. I've seen issues with when dealing directly with missing values, but never one like this.

Comment: I added the log. As you can see, there is much less rows selected with the first trial than with the second, because there is many missing data on my variable.

Comment: Maybe you have to explicitly account for missing values. Try:  `where var_ex ne 1 or missing(var_ex)`.

Comment: @floydn That would work but the point is you don't need to do that with usual tables. Also, there seems to be other cases of different behavior explained in SAS doc, so my question is more about how to use DBMS tables than how to solve this particular case.

Answer (score 2):

The best way to test how SAS is translating the data step code into database code is through the [sastrace system option](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/acreldb/63647/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a000433982.htm). Before running code, try this:

```
options sastrace=',,,db' sastraceloc=saslog;
```

Then run your code tests. When you check the log, you will see precisely how SAS is translating the code (if it can at all). If it can't, you'll see,

> ACCESS ENGINE: SQL statement was not passed to the DBMS, SAS will do the processing.

followed by a `select * from table`.

In general, if SAS cannot translate data step code into dbms-specific code, it will pull everything to locally manipulate the data. By viewing this output, you can determine precisely how to get the data step to translate into what you need.

If all else fails, you can use explicit SQL pass-through. The code in parentheses operates the same way as if you're running SQL directly from some other client.

```
proc sql;
connect to odbc(datasrc='source' user='username' pass='password');
    create table want as
        select * from connection to odbc
            (<code specific to your dbms language>);
disconnect from odbc;
quit;
```

Comment: I can't quite get it to work. The sastrace option prints the following :
`SELECT  <list of all variables> FROM TABLE where (VAR_EX <> 1 )`.
I'm not sure how to use explicit SQL exactly : am I to put the WHERE clause inside the parentheses ?

Comment: Correct. Essentially, here's what is happening:

`connect to odbc` - Establishes a connection to your database | 
`create table want as` - Creates a new table in SAS  |
`select * from connection to obdc` - Pull everything from the "subquery" you made on the database into the table you are making in SAS | 
`(<code specific to your dbms language>)` - Think of this as a subquery, except you are executing it directly on your database | 
`disconnect from odbc` - Ends the SAS connection to odbc

Comment: I'm having a bit of troubles with access rights here. I'll let you know as soon as I can try !

Comment: I keep getting the following error : `ERROR: CLI describe error: [MySQL][ODBC 5.1 Driver][mysqld-5.5.15-log]SELECT command denied to user 'sas_vincent`. I can't figure out why that is, because I do have the select rights. Have you any idea what could be the issue here ? I can't delete or update tables, but I shouldn't need that to select rows should I ?